# IntegrityError :UNIQUE constraint failed: theatre_audience.ticketId

Tags: python, django, uuid

I am trying to create a Django application to assign seats for the audience in a theatre(for live performances). Whenever I try to add a new audience, I cannot add more than one audience. It gives UNIQUE constraint failed error. Here, in my code, I am trying to create a ticketId using the UUID field. But, it is not getting saved for more than one audience.

**my model**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
class Audience(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    ticketId = models.UUIDField(
            primary_key = True,
            default = uuid.uuid4(),
            editable = False
        )
    seatNo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**my application**

```
def occupy(request, pname):
    arr = [i for i in range(1,Total_seats+1)]
    inst = Audience()
    inst.name = pname
    num = Audience.objects.values_list('seatNo')
    print(num)
    for i in num:
        v = i[0]
        arr.remove(i[0])
    print(arr)
    if(len(arr)<1):
        msg="All seats are occupied"
        context={"msg":msg}
        return render(request,"theatre/ERROR.html",context)
    else:
        seatn = random.choice(arr)
        inst.seatNo = seatn
        inst.save()
        temp = Audience.objects.get(seatNo = seatn)
        context = {"temp":temp}
        return render(request, "theatre/show.html", context)
```

I am getting error in the following line
The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: theatre_audience.ticketId) was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
    inst.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default = uuid.uuid4(),` executes `uuid4()` once only at the time that the class definition is processed and therefore `default` will be the same value for *all* new `Audience` records that do not provide an explicit value for `ticketId`. That would violate the unique constraint of the primary key field.

You can pass a callable as the default, so make that the function itself (without calling it):

```
ticketId = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key = True,
        default = uuid.uuid4,    # do not call, just pass the callable
        editable = False
    )
```

will fix the problem. Alternatively you can manually generate new UUID every time you create an `Audience` record:

```
inst = Audience(ticketId=uuid.uuid64())
```

Comment: after hours of searching, finally correct answer!